# Enabling Views custom module causes an Ajax HTTP error on Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-7, view

I'm working on a custom module that will describe an external table to the Views module. Inside my module folder I have the required mymodule.views.inc file. However, whenever this file is present and my custom module is enabled Drupal constantly gives Ajax HTTP Error pop ups when I use a site feature that has Ajax (any of the spinning daisies trigger this). The pop up always contains the module code in mymodule.views.inc after it says Ajax Error. The weird thing is every time I load the front page the PHP code in mymodule.views.inc is always displayed on the top of the front page.

I've seen this problem on SO and other sites a lot, but most of the time it can be traced back to an updated jquery.js file or a php.ini setting that will give scripts more time to run. So far neither of those fixes have worked. The only way I can make it go away for now is to either disable my custom module, or rename mymodule.views.inc to something else.

Here's an example of what the message looks like (not verbatim copy, since I can't copy from these alert messages in Chrome).

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /?q=admin/structure/views/view/viewiamtryingtocreate/preview/page/ajax
StatusText: parseerror
ResponseText: /*
* header file to my mymodule.views.inc
* file I wrote
*/

//more php code follows

//lots of unicode characters intermittently show up in my source code
\u003C\/div\u003E\n...

//source code continues with lots of unicode characters, not sure what's at the bottom because the alert box is bigger than my screen and I can't scroll on it
```

Does anyone else know what could be going on?

Comment: Can you show us your mymodule.views.inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Syntax error hiding at the top of mymodule.views.inc. There was some weird formatting before the opening PHP tag. Not sure why php --syntax-check mymodule.php didn't catch it (I copied mymodule.views.inc to mymodule.php so that I could run the syntax checker on it).

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by drupalforfirebug, disabling drupal for firebug should help. or else this [patch](http://drupal.org/files/issues/updating_detection_of_headers_for_d7.patch) should work.

Comment: I'm not seeing this module when I do `find /var/www/mywebroot/ -iname drupalforfirebug.module`. Is this included in some other module?